# How to print a random number from a set, except from one or two of the numbers?

Tags: python, random

I want to print a random number from 1 to 10, but I do not want to include 3 or 4.

I know that I need

```
print randint(1,11)
```

to print a random number, but how do I make sure that 3 or 4 are not generated?

Comment: Try [**`random.choice`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)`({1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many ways is using `random.choice()`, which returns a random element from the non-empty sequence:

```
>>> import random
>>> a = range(1,11)
>>> a.remove(3)
>>> a.remove(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> random.choice(a)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Allows you to clearly show, and easily edit, what you *don't* want in your set:

```
a = random.choice(list(set(range(1, 11)) - {3, 4}))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more pythonic way to do this, but here is my solution!

```
import random

def printSet(min, max, *excepting):
    r = random.randint(min, max)
    while True:
        if r not in excepting:
            return r
        r = random.randint(min, max)

print printSet(0, 100, 5, 25, 6, 2, 1)
```